# How to resize LVM group wheen 4 partitions already in system?

Tags: linux, lvm, partition

Centos, I have already expanded Virtual disk in Vmware, now i need to add additional space to LVM Group but most tutorials out there are saying to create new partition and add it to LVM. Since there is a limit four partitions i can't do that way.

How i would do it in this situation ?

```
Filesystem            size  used  aval. %used. mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      328G  293G   18G  95%    /
/dev/sda1              99M   13M   82M  14%    /boot
tmpfs                1006M     0 1006M   0%    /dev/shm

Disk /dev/sda: 590.5 GB, 590558003200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 71797 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/sda2              14       19581   157179960   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda3           19582       23497    31455270   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda4           23498       44384   167774827+  8e  Linux LVM

Nr  Begining      End     Size     Type   Filesystem     Flag    
 1     32,3kB    107MB   107MB     main   ext3           boot
 2     107MB     161GB   161GB     main                  lvm      
 3     161GB     193GB   32,2GB    main                  lvm      
 4     193GB     365GB   172GB     main                  lvm      
       365GB     591GB   225GB            Free space
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are wrong, you can have 4 PRIMARY partitions, OR 3 PRIMARY and a large number of extended partitions (about another 64?) on one disk.  Each of these type of partitions will be accessible by Linux and can be put together into a VG.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/424678/how-to-resize-root-lvm-partition-in-fedora-without-livecd-or-rebooting/424765#424765

Answer (score 1):

You should reboot the system to a rescue media of some sort that includes the LVM tools, and a partition editor.  Extend the 4th partition to the new end of the virtual drive.  Then use `pvresize` to enlarge that physical volume.

Another solution would have been to create an additional Virtual Disk instead of expanding the existing disk.  Setup a partition on the new drive, use `pvcreate` to prepare it as a physical volume.  Then use `vgextend` to add the new new drive to the volume group.

As in all cases.  It would be a very good idea to verify that you have good working backups before messing around with partitions/lvm.

Comment: After pvresize, I think that you have to do a vgresize as well.